# Widget is not rebuilding when notifyListeners is called

Tags: flutter, dart, state, provider

i am trying to create a login page so that when i am logged-in, the Navigationrail Widget lets me access all its destinations. When logged off i can only access two pages.

I am using Provider in login.dart to triger a widget rebuild in main.dart .

here is the code.

login.dart

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:httptest/depand/XmlLogin.dart';
import 'package:httptest/main.dart';


void login(String userName, String passWord) async {
  Response response;
  Dio dio = Dio();

  dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
    onResponse: (response, handler) {
      var token = getToken.Transcribe(response.data);

      LoginProvider obj = LoginProvider();
      obj.providestate(true);

      print(token);
      print("logged in");

      handler.next(response);
    },
  ));

  try { 
    //Http Post method
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

class LoginProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool loginstate = false;
  void providestate(bool val) {
    loginstate = val;
    print("loginstate changed to $loginstate");
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> pages = [Page0(), Page1(), Page2(), Placeholder()];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
                child: ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginProvider>(
              create: (context) => LoginProvider(),
              child: Builder(
                builder: (context) {
                  return Consumer<LoginProvider>(
                      builder: (context, provider, child) {
                    return NavigationRail(
                      extended: constraints.maxWidth >= 600,
                      minExtendedWidth: 200,
                      destinations: [

                        NavigationRailDestination(),
                        NavigationRailDestination(),
                        NavigationRailDestination(),
                        NavigationRailDestination()

                      ],

                      selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                      onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                        if (provider.loginstate) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = value;
                          });
                          print("On");
                        } else {
                          if (value == 0 || value == 3) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex = value;
                            });
                            print("OFF");
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  });
                },
              ),
            )),
            Expanded(
              child: Scaffold(
                body: IndexedStack(
                  index: selectedIndex,
                  children: pages,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

the login  goes through but i Still cant access pages 1 and 2.

it prints out 'loginstate changed to True' from login.dart.

Answer (score -1):

To ensure access place a provider in a widget tree something like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => LoginProvider()),
...
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then in child widgets access it using either `Consumer` to listen changes or `Provider.of` when just calling a method.

```
Consumer<LoginProvider>(
  builder: (context, provider, child) {
    ...
  },
)

Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).login(userName, passWord);
```

See [Simple app state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for the full example.